# Can't assign a shortcut to "Randomize"

Tags: interface, shortcut, customization

When I navigate through the menu to **Randomize** and try to assign a shortcut, it doesn't take.

[image]

Trying to assign a shortcut manually isn't working either:

[image]

I've tried lots of different shortcut combinations, so I don't think it's a key conflict.

What could be the problem?

<sub>(Using Ver2.9.0)</sub>

Comment: Very strange. I just tried with 2.90 and 2.90.1 and it works for me. It doesn't show the shortcut keys in the menu but the shortcut works.

Comment: Once you set the shortcut, do you try it in Edit Mode?

Comment: what all combinations have you tried?

Comment: @SHikhaMittal I've tried all modifier keys in combination with R.

Comment: Other things to note: I have the following enabled: Emulate Numpad, Emulate 3-btn Mouse, RMB to select (classic style). And I'm on macOS, so Cmd key is a thing.

Comment: @Mentalist look ctrl r is a short cut for edge loop , shift r is for repeat last action , alt r is for clear rotation , try adding some other key from r because its kinda reserved

Comment: @SHikhaMittal Ah, thanks! It was so simple. When I searched "alt r" in the keymap nothing came up under the Edit Mode or 3D View categories, so I thought I could use it. Ctrl Alt O is working for me now. Although, strangely the shortcut is still not shown in the menu, even after assigning it. I've noticed some shortcuts aren't shown in the menus for whatever reason.

Comment: @SHikhaMittal Since you've basically answered my question in a comment, why don't you post as an answer and we can close this case, and you can get some rep.

Answer (score -1):

So basically what you are facing is a shortage of appropriate shortcut options . You want to assign a shortcut which has R in it but you know that r is for rotating in all the modes , so you could've tried ctrl R but thats loop cut , alt R is clear rotation and shift r is repeat last action , so the final option is that you can go and add some other key like combinations of O for the shortcut because we are running out of shortcuts

Comment: I'm sorry, I had to un-accept your answer because although reassigning the shortcut to another key such as O did solve the problem for me (and thank you!), the reason you are giving for *why* `Alt R` doesn't work is incorrect. Consider this: Clear Rotation is exclusively an Object Mode command, and *isn't possible* to do in Edit Mode. Actually, `Alt R` and `Ctrl Alt R` are both unassigned in Edit Mode. To test this, I assigned `Alt R` to the Warp command and it works! so there is no clear reason why that shortcut can't be assigned to Randomize (yet `Ctrl Alt O` can). I'm still open to answers.